# PHP website not loging to CMS after migration from apache to nginx

Tags: php, nginx, model-view-controller

I have a PHP website that has a CMS, but ever since we migrated the website from apache to nginx, users can't log in to the CMS.

I don't know much about PHP and nginx, but here are some things that I managed to identify and believe that might have something to do with the problem:

- When running in apache, the login form makes a request to ajax/cms_users/login.php, and then the cms index is called (the dashboard appears). That is not happening when running in nginx, where only the login.php is called.
  [This image shows this in the Network tab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stU6j.png)

**↓The ajax.php**

```
<?php

include_once("config.php");

include_once("verificaLogado.php");

$modulo = $_CMS_CONFIG["modulo_padrao"];
if(trim($_REQUEST["modulo"]) <> "")
{   
    $modulo = trim($_REQUEST["modulo"]);    
}

$acao = $_CMS_CONFIG["acao_padrao"];
if(trim($_GET["acao"]) <> "")
{   
    $acao = trim($_GET["acao"]);    
} else if(trim($_POST["acao"]) <> "")
{   
    $acao = trim($_POST["acao"]);   
}
?>
<script language="javascript">
    console.log("<?php echo $modulo; ?>");
    console.log("<?php echo $acao; ?>");
</script>
<?php
$status_operacao = "";
if(trim($_REQUEST["status_operacao"]) <> "")
{   
    $status_operacao = trim($_REQUEST["status_operacao"]);  
}

$id = null;
if(trim($_REQUEST["id"]) <> "")
{   
    $id = trim($_REQUEST["id"]);  
}

if(file_exists(ROOT_CMS . "classes/models/" . $modulo . "_model.php")){
include_once(ROOT_CMS . "classes/models/" . $modulo . "_model.php");}
if(file_exists(ROOT_CMS . "classes/views/" . $modulo . "_view.php")){
include_once(ROOT_CMS . "classes/views/" . $modulo . "_view.php");}
if(file_exists(ROOT_CMS . "classes/controllers/" . $modulo . "_controller.php")){
include_once(ROOT_CMS . "classes/controllers/" . $modulo . "_controller.php");}

$error = "";

?>
<script language="javascript">
    console.log("<?php echo $modulo; ?>");
    console.log("<?php echo $acao; ?>");
    CMS_MODULO = "<?php echo $modulo; ?>";
    CMS_ACAO = "<?php echo $acao; ?>";
</script>
<?php

if(file_exists(ROOT_CMS . "classes/" . $modulo . ".php"))
{   
    $classe = $modulo."_controller";                
    $controller = new $classe();
    if(trim($acao) == "")
    {$acao = "acaoPadrao";}

    if($acao == "login" || !method_exists($classe,"valida_permissao") || $controller->valida_permissao($modulo))
    {   
        if(method_exists($classe,$acao))
        {           
            if($acao == "get_registros") {
                $controller->$acao(null, null);
            } else {
                $controller->$acao();
            }
        }       
        else if(method_exists($classe,"acaoPadrao"))
        {           
            $controller->acaoPadrao();
        }
    } else {
        $error = "401";
    }
} else {
    $error = "404";
} 

if(trim($error) != "") {
    ob_clean();
    ?>
    <iframe class="error-frame fullScreen" src="<?php echo ROOT_SERVER . ROOT . $error; ?>.html"></iframe>
    <?php
    die();
}

?>
```

**↓The login verification (verificaLogado.php):**

```
<?php

// Verifica sessão ou tentativa de login
if((!isset($_SESSION["btLogin"]) || $_SESSION["btLogin"] == false || $_SESSION["ROOT_SESSION"] <> ROOT) &&
   $_REQUEST["modulo"] != "cms_usuarios" &&
   $_REQUEST["acao"] != "login"
  ) {

    // Verifica cookies
    $btLogin = false;
    if(intval($_COOKIE[$projectName . "_idUser"]) > 0) {
        carrega_classe("cms_usuarios");
        $user = new cms_usuarios();
        $btLogin = $user->login(intval($_COOKIE[$projectName . "_idUser"]));
    }

    if(!$btLogin) {
        // Se falhou em todas, garante o logout e mandar para autenticação
        $_SESSION["btLogin"] = false;
        header ("location: " . ROOT_SERVER . ROOT . "login.php");
        die();
    }
}

?>
```

**The login.php have, mostly, the html for the login form, so I won't put it here.**

**↓And that's the conf.d file for the website in nginx:**

```
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_types  text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml text/x-component application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml image/x-icon image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject ap$

map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default +1M;
    text/cache-manifest 0;
    text/html 0;
    text/xml 0;
    application/xml 0;
    application/json 0;
    application/rss+xml +1h;
    application/atom+xml +1h;
    image/x-icon +1w;
    image/gif +1M;
    image/png +1M;
    image/jpg +1M;
    image/jpeg +1M;
    video/ogg +1M;
    audio/ogg +1M;
    video/mp4 +1M;
    video/webm +1M;
    text/x-component +1M;
    application/x-font-ttf +1M;
    font/opentype +1M;
    application/x-font-woff +1M;
    image/svg+xml +1M;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject +1M;
    text/css +1w;
    application/javascript +1w;
    application/x-javascript +1w;
}

server {

        listen 80;

        server_name formalegno.com.br www.formalegno.com.br;
        root /ftp/Websites/formalegno;
          location /{
                return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }
    error_page 401 /401.html;
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 /500.html;
    error_page 401 /401.html;
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    expires $expires;
        rewrite ^/cms?$ /cms/index.php;
        rewrite ^/cms/?$ /cms/index.php;
         rewrite ^/download/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/(.*)?$ /custom_file_download.php?modulo=$1&id=$2&campo=$3&titulo=$4&titulo_def=$5;
    rewrite ^/download/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/(.*)/?$ /custom_file_download.php?modulo=$1&id=$2&campo=$3&titulo=$4&titulo_def=$5;
    rewrite ^/download/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/(.*)?$ /custom_file_download.php?modulo=$1&id=$2&campo=$3&titulo=$4;
    rewrite ^/download/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/(.*)/?$ /custom_file_download.php?modulo=$1&id=$2&campo=$3&titulo=$4;
    rewrite ^/idioma/([a-z0-9-_]+)?$ /index.php?lang=$1;
    rewrite ^/idioma/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1;
    rewrite ^/lang/([a-z0-9-_]+)?$ /index.php?lang=$1;
    rewrite ^/lang/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1;
    rewrite ^/ajax/contato/enviar?$ /post-contact.php last;
    rewrite ^/ajax/contato/enviar/?$ /post-contact.php last;
    rewrite ^/ajax/cadastro/enviar?$ /post-cadastro.php last;
    rewrite ^/ajax/cadastro/enviar/?$ /post-cadastro.php last;
    rewrite ^/ajax/blog/posts?$ /blog-lista.php last;
    rewrite ^/ajax/blog/posts/?$ /blog-lista.php last;
    rewrite ^/ajax/representantes/([0-9]+)?$ /representantes-lista.php?id_estado=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/ajax/representantes/([0-9]+)/?$ /representantes-lista.php?id_estado=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/ajax/download/(.*)?$ /custom_file_download.php?key=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/ajax/([a-z0-9-_]+)?$ /ajax-data.php?id=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/ajax/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /ajax-data.php?id=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/ajax/(.*)?$ /$1 last;
    rewrite ^/index?$ /redirect.php?module=index last;
    rewrite ^/index/?$ /index.php last;
    rewrite ^/home?$ /redirect.php?module=home last;
    rewrite ^/home/?$ /index.php last;
    rewrite ^/search?$ /redirect.php?module=search last;
    rewrite ^/search/?$ /search.php last;
    rewrite ^/sobre?$ /redirect.php?module=sobre last;
    rewrite ^/sobre/?$ /sobre.php last;
    rewrite ^/colecao?$ /redirect.php?module=colecao last;
    rewrite ^/colecao/?$ /colecao.php last;
    rewrite ^/encontre?$ /redirect.php?module=encontre last;
    rewrite ^/encontre/?$ /encontre.php last;
    rewrite ^/representantes?$ /redirect.php?module=representantes last;
    rewrite ^/representantes/?$ /representantes.php last;
    rewrite ^/produtos?$ /redirect.php?module=produtos last;
    rewrite ^/produtos/?$ /produtos.php last;
    rewrite ^/produtos/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)?$ /redirect.php?module=produtos&titulo=$1&id=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/produtos/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /produtos-detalhe.php?titulo=$1&id=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/produtos/categoria/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)?$ /redirect.php?module=produtos&acao=categoria&titulo=$1&id=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/produtos/categoria/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /produtos.php?tit=$1&id=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/blog?$ /redirect.php?module=blog last;
    rewrite ^/blog/?$ /blog.php last;
    rewrite ^/blog/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)?$ /redirect.php?module=blog&titulo=$1&id=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/blog/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /blog-detalhe.php?titulo=$1&id=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/blog/categoria/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)?$ /redirect.php?module=blog&acao=categoria&titulo_categoria=$1&id_categoria=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/blog/categoria/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /blog.php?titulo_categoria=$1&id_categoria=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/cadastro?$ /redirect.php?module=cadastro last;
    rewrite ^/cadastro/?$ /cadastro.php last;
    rewrite ^/contato?$ /redirect.php?module=contato last;
    rewrite ^/contato/?$ /contato.php last;
}

server {

        listen 443 ssl http2;

        server_name formalegno.com.br www.formalegno.com.br;

        # Bad Bot Blocker
        include /etc/nginx/bots.d/ddos.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/bots.d/blockbots.conf;

        root /ftp/Websites/formalegno;

        include /etc/nginx/global/wordpress-producao-base.conf;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/formalegno.com.br/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/formalegno.com.br/privkey.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
        error_page 500 /500.html;
        error_page 401 /401.html;
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 /500.html;
        error_page 401 /401.html;
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        expires $expires;
        rewrite ^/cms?$ /cms/index.php;
        rewrite ^/cms/?$ /cms/index.php;
        rewrite ^/download/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/(.*)?$ /custom_file_download.php?modulo=$1&id=$2&campo=$3&titulo=$4&titulo_def=$5;
        rewrite ^/download/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/(.*)/?$ /custom_file_download.php?modulo=$1&id=$2&campo=$3&titulo=$4&titulo_def=$5;
        rewrite ^/download/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/(.*)?$ /custom_file_download.php?modulo=$1&id=$2&campo=$3&titulo=$4;
        rewrite ^/download/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/(.*)/?$ /custom_file_download.php?modulo=$1&id=$2&campo=$3&titulo=$4;
        rewrite ^/idioma/([a-z0-9-_]+)?$ /index.php?lang=$1;
        rewrite ^/idioma/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1;
        rewrite ^/lang/([a-z0-9-_]+)?$ /index.php?lang=$1;
        rewrite ^/lang/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1;
        rewrite ^/ajax/contato/enviar?$ /post-contact.php last;
        rewrite ^/ajax/contato/enviar/?$ /post-contact.php last;
        rewrite ^/ajax/cadastro/enviar?$ /post-cadastro.php last;
        rewrite ^/ajax/cadastro/enviar/?$ /post-cadastro.php last;
        rewrite ^/ajax/blog/posts?$ /blog-lista.php last;
        rewrite ^/ajax/blog/posts/?$ /blog-lista.php last;
        rewrite ^/ajax/representantes/([0-9]+)?$ /representantes-lista.php?id_estado=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/ajax/representantes/([0-9]+)/?$ /representantes-lista.php?id_estado=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/ajax/download/(.*)?$ /custom_file_download.php?key=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/ajax/([a-z0-9-_]+)?$ /ajax-data.php?id=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/ajax/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /ajax-data.php?id=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/ajax/(.*)?$ /$1 last;
        rewrite ^/index?$ /redirect.php?module=index last;
        rewrite ^/index/?$ /index.php last;
        rewrite ^/home?$ /redirect.php?module=home last;
        rewrite ^/home/?$ /index.php last;
        rewrite ^/search?$ /redirect.php?module=search last;
        rewrite ^/search/?$ /search.php last;
        rewrite ^/sobre?$ /redirect.php?module=sobre last;
        rewrite ^/sobre/?$ /sobre.php last;
        rewrite ^/colecao?$ /redirect.php?module=colecao last;
        rewrite ^/colecao/?$ /colecao.php last;
        rewrite ^/encontre?$ /redirect.php?module=encontre last;
        rewrite ^/encontre/?$ /encontre.php last;
        rewrite ^/representantes?$ /redirect.php?module=representantes last;
        rewrite ^/representantes/?$ /representantes.php last;
        rewrite ^/produtos?$ /redirect.php?module=produtos last;
        rewrite ^/produtos/?$ /produtos.php last;
        rewrite ^/produtos/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)?$ /redirect.php?module=produtos&titulo=$1&id=$2 last;
        rewrite ^/produtos/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /produtos-detalhe.php?titulo=$1&id=$2 last;
        rewrite ^/produtos/categoria/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)?$ /redirect.php?module=produtos&acao=categoria&titulo=$1&id=$2 last;
        rewrite ^/produtos/categoria/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /produtos.php?tit=$1&id=$2 last;
        rewrite ^/blog?$ /redirect.php?module=blog last;
        rewrite ^/blog/?$ /blog.php last;
        rewrite ^/blog/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)?$ /redirect.php?module=blog&titulo=$1&id=$2 last;
        rewrite ^/blog/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /blog-detalhe.php?titulo=$1&id=$2 last;
        rewrite ^/blog/categoria/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)?$ /redirect.php?module=blog&acao=categoria&titulo_categoria=$1&id_categoria=$2 last;
        rewrite ^/blog/categoria/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /blog.php?titulo_categoria=$1&id_categoria=$2 last;
        rewrite ^/cadastro?$ /redirect.php?module=cadastro last;
        rewrite ^/cadastro/?$ /cadastro.php last;
        rewrite ^/contato?$ /redirect.php?module=contato last;
        rewrite ^/contato/?$ /contato.php last;
}
```

As I said, I don't know much about PHP and nginx, so I'm not sure if the code I provided is of any help to understand the issue.
To anyone open to help me with this, I'm happy to provide more information.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your access permissions. Does the var `ROOT_CMS` exist in the Javascript setting?

Comment: Check your `phpinfo()`. put in `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your PHP and see what errors in the error log it gives you. Ensure your account is correctly set up with the correct PHP.ini customisation details.

Comment: @Martin You're talking about the info.php file, right? That was only `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in there. I added `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top but I didn't find where to look at to see the logs. As for the `ROOT_CMS` existing in Javascript... where can I check it? I believe it does, since the website domain didn't change in the migration, only the server.